# Is there a way to access data from a tableau table on a website?

Tags: tableau-api, data-science

I am wanting to build a tool for my own use, and possibly others in the future, is there any way for me to access a tableau table that is hosted at a given url?

I want to be able to rip the data from it and use it to do my own calculations. Does Tableau have way to do this or are there any neat tricks in the community?

(I am a dev so feel free to be as technical as possible)

Comment: Are you asking how to extract a tableau tables data(to something you can use like .csv) or is it a question around hosting? Do you have tableau server or will you be hosting the table on tableau public?

Comment: Yeah I want to extract the data from the table to any usable format for myself. The table is on a 3rd party website.

Comment: Yeah, I would think it really depends. If the people who own the view/table wanted to make the data in easy accessible they could allow you to append the url with .csv or add a button so you could pull the data. But they may not want to allow people access the raw data sitting behind a view and so lock it down. What's the site?

Comment: viscioussyndicate.com I have contacted them directly too. Just hoping to find out if it's something I can do with tableau or not. :)

Best case scenario, they share their data with me in a more accessible format.

Comment: Cant get at it. They could do this: https://public.tableau.com/en-us/s/blog/2014/04/exporting-csv-made-simple. Best of luck anyway

Comment: Sorry I can't spell xD http://www.vicioussyndicate.com/

Comment: I agree with @lampbob that "It depends"...  Another resource to try for Tableau Questions is their Q&A Forum: https://community.tableau.com/community/forums

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can access data from Tableau tables on a website using one of these Tableau APIs:

REST API - https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/api/rest_api/en-us/help.htm

Javascript API - https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/api/js_api/en-us/JavaScriptAPI/js_api.htm